# To use object call or static call in a function/method for java?

Tags: java, object, static

Should I use a normal method that needs an object to call it or a static function method for an increment in the value of a data member of an object. Such as

```
public void incSize() {
    this.size++;
}
```

or such as

```
public static void incSize(Number num1) {
    num1.size++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, where the logic and purpose of the function is intrinsically bound to a single object, use a member function instead of a static one. It means that all the operations you can perform on an object are grouped logically by the object you perform the operation on, which is easier to use.

In my opinion, and likely the opinions of many others, it's much easier to see what's going on with:

```
foo.incSize();
```

Compared to:

```
Foo.incSize(foo);
```

---

Static functions are good for describing computation that's relevant to a class, but not necessarily dependent on having an object of that class. For example, `Integer.parseInt` is static because the functionality of parsing to an integer is relevant to the integer class, but is still usable when you don't have an object of that class. Again, compare:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("0");
```

To:

```
Integer x;
x.parseInt("0");
```

Comment: Would not it be just incSize(foo)?  Because it is a static method, hence, cannot be called by an object, but it's parameter can be an object! That is what is confusing me! Which one is better?

Comment: For a static function you still need to specify what class it comes from - in this case `Foo`. Note that `static` means it can't be called *on* an object, but it can still be called *with* an object. Which is "better"? In this case, a normal member function, for the reasons above.